# Long term branch alternative with git?

Tags: git

I am writing my thesis in mathematics and am about to publish my first paper. So far, I have used git for version control. At this point in time, the text for the paper and the thesis will have to diverge: the thesis will be a lot more detailed than the paper, which will have to be rather concise.

How do I manage this situation with git? I am not quite sure which git option is the best for me. I thought about creating a separate branch for the paper and then cherry-picking commits, but apparently branches are not supposed to be permanent (is that true?). Ideally, I would like a solution  where I have to manually duplicate as little as possible as I go about writing both projects simultaneously.

Comment: Do you have any link to "branches are not supposed to be permanent"? I haven't heard that advice before. Also, how would you like to _use_ version control in your further writing; are you trying to make it so you can make certain changes to both versions and other changes to just one or the other?

Comment: I believe that your approach is wrong, this is not a problem to solve with git, but with a sound document structure in your work files. You need to figure out two main documents, one for the paper and the other for the thesis. Then, include carefully every piece of reusable work in one or the other. Git will reflect the history of your work and eventually it may have branches for different directions of your work, but not for the different content structure.

Comment: @JeffBowman: No, I don't have a link to that statement, just word of mouth of a colleague. You are exactly right: I would like to make some commits which change both versions at once (e.g. typos) and some commits that just change one of the two versions.

Comment: @PA: Thanks for the comment, I guess you are right. I just thought that this is something that git should be able to do, and was trying to figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Branches can be as permanent as you want them to be.  You can create and destroy them just like files.

If your branches (or more specifically the files containing the patches in a cherry pick) diverge too much, cherry pick will not be able to find the patches to make the changes.

If one project is a superset of the other one, you can use 'subtree' (see 'git help subtree').  Which makes changes in the subproject trivially easy to include in the super project.  (see also the older command 'submodule')